# Android parse String / JSON issue

Tags: android, string, json

I have a little question about parsing a JSON string in Android. I'm trying to parse this JSON :

```
{
   "error":504,
   "result":"[\"USRL3C4NAEL84727\",\"USR1HZE4UN5289H1\",\"USR46476WQB92M84\",\"USR4ZQ193YGRK782\"]"
}
```

The part that I need actually is to parse the `result`. I did try this :

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
            int error = Integer.parseInt(jObj.optString("error","0"));
            String errorMessage = jObj.optString("result","");
            if(error==504){
                JSONArray savedCodes = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < savedCodes.length(); i++) {
                    String returnString = savedCodes.getString(i);
                    Log.e("","returnString : "+returnString);
                }
            }
```

But it's throwing me an exception :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value ["USR9BA13IZG27H93","USRI818369RH919Y","USRWT7612CQV4375","USR7739R644X84A1"] at result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

So I guess it's not `JSONArray` and I need to know how to parse the result part and get this at the end :

```
String 1 = USR9BA13IZG27H93
String 2 = USRI818369RH919Y
and etc...
```

Any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse this JSON in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605077/how-can-i-parse-this-json-in-android) and about a million other questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Go to google and search for "Android JSON Parsing tutorial".

Comment: I know it is a possible duplicate,but I ask that question because in some situations I can receive that as a `result` and I need to devide the string between `""` so I can insert them into Database

Comment: Quickly edit your question with your doubt fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this :

```
String errorMessage = jObj.optString("result","");
if(error==504){
     String first = errorMessage.replace("[", "");
     String second = first.replace("]", "");
     String third = second.replace("\"", "");
     String[] split = third.split(",");

     for(int i=0;i< split.length;i++)
         Log.e("","SPLIT : "+split[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this Android JSON parsing tutorial will be useful:
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

there is a tutorial here on it

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/