# how to parse the jsonObject in android?

Tags: java, android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I parse this JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605077/how-can-i-parse-this-json-in-android)

I have a requirement, where i need to parse the jsonObject. My format will be

```
[{"music":{"artist":"Dire Straits","album":"The Best of Dire Straits","genre":"Pop","title":"Sultans Of Swing"}},{"camera":{"picture":"http:\/\/sp.sony-europe.com\/da\/594\/195346.jpeg","model":"Digital Still Camera - H Series - DSC-HX200V","make":"Sony","price":510}},{"book":{"description":"What is self, and how can a self come out of inanimate matter?' Is the riddle that drove Douglas Hofstadter to write this extraordinary book. In order to impart his highly original and personal view on the core mystery of human existence - the intangible sensation of 'I'-ness - Hofstadter defines the playful yet seemingly paradoxical notion of 'strange loop', and explicates this idea using analogies from many disciplines.","authors":"Douglas R Hofstadter","price":650,"id":40724766,"title":"G\u00f6del, Escher, Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid"}}]
```

How to parse this ? Help me?

Comment: Actually, it is not a jsonObject, but [jsonArray](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google: Android parse json](https://www.google.nl/search?q=android%20parse%20json%20in%20anroid&sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=android%20parse%20json%20&oq=android%20parse%20json%20&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.1426.1426.0.1683.1.1.0.0.0.0.43.43.1.1.0...0.0...1c._-UxYDQRzqE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5f7b965ca03a6e72&biw=1366&bih=643)

First tutorial hit: [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of JSON libraries like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (or) [json-lib](http://www.json.org/) etc., to parse JSon string. They create Java objects for the json string.