# Parse this JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I parse this JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605077/how-can-i-parse-this-json-in-android)

I am following this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) to parse my json but i am unable to perform as i am confused . and even the duplicate link does not provide any reference, those users who voted to close this question can answer my question when their provided LINK does not provide any help to solve these question?

i think those who can not answer the question have no rights to edit some one's question nor have rights to close the question when their provided link does not provide any point to solve this.
Help me to parse data.

```
[
{
"id": "c200",
"name": "XYZ",
"email": "xyz@gmail.com",
},
{
"id": "c201",
"name": "Johnny",
"email": "john_johnny@gmail.com",

}]
```

**[ANSWER]**

Since it is an closed post so i am posting my answer in question:

```
//JSONArray
JSONArray hospital = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

     // getting JSON string from URL
    String json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
            contactList);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
          hospital = new JSONArray(json);

          if (hospital != null) {

            // looping through
                for (int i = 0; i < hospital.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject contacts = hospital.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = contacts.getString(TAG_HID);
            String name = contacts.getString(TAG_HNAME);
            String address = contacts.getString(TAG_HADDRESS);
            String phone1=contacts.getString(TAG_HPHONE1);
            String phone2=contacts.getString(TAG_HPHONE2);
            String fax=contacts.getString(TAG_HFAX);
            String email=contacts.getString(TAG_HEMAIL);
            String url=contacts.getString(TAG_URL);
            String hlongitude=contacts.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
            String hlatitude=contacts.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
            String hdistance=contacts.getString(TAG_HDISTANCE);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_HID, id);
            map.put(TAG_HNAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_HADDRESS, address);
            map.put(TAG_HPHONE1, phone1);
            map.put(TAG_HPHONE2, phone2);
            map.put(TAG_HFAX, fax);
            map.put(TAG_HEMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_URL, url);
            map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, hlongitude);
            map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, hlatitude);   
            map.put(TAG_HDISTANCE, hdistance);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } 
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

some coding for JSON Parser class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends NameValuePair>) contactList));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } 
        else if (method == "GET") 
        {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format((List<? extends NameValuePair>) contactList, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return json;

}
}
```

Comment: just show what you have tried, and what you want? like this you can ask..

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say, I'm assuming you're using the built-in org.json parser that Android ships with.  If you're using a different parser, consult its documentation.

Pass the json as a string to the [JSONArray constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29).