# Error when trying to get JSON object in Android

Tags: android, json, http, getjson, endpoint

I have a url that has a parameter to access a WCF service, the service reads the parameter and executes a method that performs a search that returns JSON object:

```
{
"GetUsersByNameMethodResult":[
    {
        "City":"CONTAGEM",
        "Id":11,
        "Name":"Alice"
    },
    {
        "City":"BELO HORIZONTE",
        "Id":7,
        "Name":"Marcia"
    },
    {
        "City":"RIO DE JANEIRO",
        "Id":9,
        "Name":"Marcos"
    },
]
```

}

Here my code that I use in Android:

```
 // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But whenever an error occurs while running the above code, anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: post your logcat output here...

Comment: What's the error? Post you error stack as well.

Comment: My Logcat:
06-05 16:51:31.673: E/AndroidRuntime(390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 16:51:31.673: E/AndroidRuntime(390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prologica.ticket4telmo/com.prologica.ticket4telmo.BuscaNomeActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-05 16:51:31.673: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [Parse this JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152468/parse-this-json-in-android)

It has total solution. Simply modify the code to match your json.