# What are different ways of parsing data

Tags: android, web-services, rest, parsing

I am new to android. I am currently working on an enterprise application. In this application i am working with restful web services. But i want to know different types of parsing techniques in retrieving the data from a source.

Comment: is it a valid json http://jsonlint.com/??

Comment: Can we see your latest attempt? Have you retrieved the JSON from the XML to start with? I doubt it will parse correctly with the `<string>` tag around it.

Comment: yes it is a valid json, i tried of parsing it using the following code

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: this is not valid json, it gives error here "@is_active":"True",Adam"

Comment: This isn't a valid json

Comment: Its not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first check if it's valid json. If it's then at first you'll need to parse XML then parse json from the result and parse that json.

Json parsing way is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605077/how-can-i-parse-this-json-in-android)

Try this way. It might help

```
// Get some JSON from wherever
String json = getJSONFromServer();

where json =  {"EngProjects":{"ENG":[{"@trouble_id":"289302","@resolution_id":"","@is_active":"True","@CSM":"","@subject":"Test","@owner_user_id":"23","@trouble_issue_desc":"Account Team Document","@Age":"5","@Stage":"In Queue","@Severity":"Low","@due_dtm":"","@next_step":"","@add_dtm":"4/3/2015 1:16:02 PM","@closed_dtm":"","@comment":"","@issue_id":"769","@notes_count":"0"},{"@trouble_id":"271080","@resolution_id":"","@is_active":"True","@CSM":"","@subject":"Tew","@owner_user_id":"6","@trouble_issue_desc":"Customer Carrier Portals and Logins","@Age":"315","@Stage":"Researching","@Severity":"Medium","@due_dtm":"11/17/2014","@next_step":"adsadsf","@add_dtm":"5/28/2014 9:09:18 AM","@closed_dtm":"","@comment":"adfadfasdfd","@issue_id":"780","@notes_count":"0"}]}} 

 // Parse the JSON response into an object
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

 // Get the results array
 JSONArray users = object.getJSONArray("ENG");
 for(int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
 // Each element in the results array is a JSONObject with a single
 // property "user" which is a JSONObject that contains the user data
 JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user");

 Log.e(TAG, user );
}
```

Comment: it is throwing a JSON Exception as,  value ... of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject. I think we need to convert the response to string before parsing it. Did you get my point. Thanks

Comment: in above code "json" is the value you get from server so if it's json then you don't need this line String json = getJSONFromServer();

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer i couldnt get you @sur007

Comment: Sorry, This is not working @sur007. Throwing exception. JSONException: java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: @SaiChakradharSana can you post the question with implemented code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to parse the xml, and check this on different method to use xml parse http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Then, once you get the value. You can use the JSONObject to parse the json.

[I tried with jsonlint and it is not a valid json. But if it requires that you need to parse it. Parse the xml part then get the json.]

Comment: Those are general suggestions and not really an answer.